# Limit Rendering fetchMore Items in Paginated Query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

Using Apollo client, I have a React component something like this:

```
function User() {
  const { number } = useParams();

  const { data: { user, fetchMore } } = useGetUserSuspenseQuery({
    variables: {
      number
    }
  });

  const fetchMoreBookings = async () => {
    await fetchMore({
      variables: {
        number,
        bookingsAfter: user.bookings.pageInfo.endCursor
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Heading>
        {user.displayName}
      </Heading>
      <ul>
        {user.bookings.nodes.map(booking =>
          <Booking
            key={booking.id}
            booking={booking}
          />
        )}
      <ul>
      <Link
        onClick={fetchMoreBookings}
      >
        load older
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have a merge function in the cache that handles caching the additional results.

When `load older` is clicked, the entire `User` component re-renders including the user's display name (and other user level data, omitted for simplicity).

How can I cause only the new `Booking`s to appear without re-rendering the whole component? I tried extracting a `Bookings` component, but that did nothing. Is this inevitable if the connection is nested? This must be a common scenario.

Answer (score 0):

That is how react basically works. When you click `load older`, react will run a reconciliation algorithm in your component to create the new Virtual DOM (Virtual DOM is just a JS representation of the actual DOM using Objects). This is what we call re-rendering in react. This new Virtual DOM is then compared with the current Virtual DOM, and then react will only apply the difference of this comparison to the actual DOM.

So in your case even though your component is fully re-rendered, final DOM mutations will be done only for the new data that is coming in.

Also, react gives us the below APIs to optimize this re-rendering process.

- React.memo
- PureComponent

By using these APIs, we can tell react that it does not have to run the re-conciliation algorithm on components wrapped with these APIs, unless either State / Props are changed

So, in your case, you can extract the basic user information to a new child component that is wrapped with React.memo, so that when you click `load older`, react can bail out of running re-conciliation on that component.

However I would only suggest to do this only when the need comes, since I feel this would be a premature optimization otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is, even if I extract and memoize all the parts of the User that surround the list of bookings, the whole User component re-renders. I think the only solution is to query the bookings separately, so I can refetch just that instead of the whole User graph. That is to say, refetching nested connections is a React anti-pattern.

Comment: You are fighting here with the core architecture of react. React would not know what changed in a component unless it fully re-renders it. Any child component wrapped in useMemo will not get rerenderd if that child component's props were not changed. If you want your entire component to not rerender, then you need to look at other frameworks like Solidjs which uses signals that will track where in DOM a signal is used and any change in signal will be directly synced with those parts of the DOM instead of triggering a rerender inside the compoment